# my swing timer is running independently

Tags: java, swing, timer

i am an average programmer trying to program a traffic light. i have all my codes in place but my swing timer is giving me problem.i want all the bulbs to countdown to zero.in these order, red first, amber next, green last. i want it to do this for ten times but when i run it in a loop, i keep getting the timer running independently. all i want now is that the countdown should complete before another one start. the loop shows to complete before the gui starts. please help me with alternative or corrections if possible. thanks in anticipation!

```
        // setting values that each bulb uses to count down
            private  int red_time = 10;
            private  int amb_time = 3;
            private  int grn_time = 10;

         private int speed = 500; // 0.5 second
          Queue myqueue = new LinkedList();
           Queue dupqueue = new LinkedList(); //this queue contains same        elements as myqueue. used to get next signal
            public int cars1;
            public int cars2;
            public int cars3;
            public int cars4;
           Timer timer;
            int counter = 0;
           /**
            * Creates new form bulbs
            */
public bulbs() {
    initComponents();
    red1.setText(null);
    amb1.setText(null);
    grn1.setText(null);

    red2.setText(null);
    amb2.setText(null);
    grn2.setText(null);

    // the first view sees only the red bulb on
    red1.setEnabled(true);
    amb1.setEnabled(false);
    grn1.setEnabled(false);
    /* my algorithm
   1.   Load ← [ L1,L2,L3,L4]
   2.   RESULT_QUEUE ← COMPARE (LOAD)
   3.   NEXT_SIGNAL ← ADD(RESULT_QUEUE)
   4.   COUNTER ← 0
   5.   WHILE (!EMPTY(NEXT_SIGNAL && COUNTER MOD != 10)):
   a.   PREDICTION_LIST ←ADD(LOAD)
   b.   MOVE ← POP(NEXT_SIGNAL)
   c.   RELEASE (MOVE, LOAD) UNTIL TIMER ==0
   d.   NEXT_SIGNAL ← ADD(MOVE)
   e.   LOAD ← GENERATE(LOAD)
   f.   COUNTER++
   6.   RESULT_QUEUE ← PREDICT(LOAD)
   7.   NEXT_SIGNAL  ← ADD (RESULT_QUEUE)
   8.   GOTO 4
   9.   EXIT

    */
    Car car = new Car();
    Compare com = new Compare();
    Store store = new Store();


    //prediction list for all lanes
    int [] pred1 = new int [10];
    int [] pred2 = new int [10];
    int [] pred3 = new int [10];
    int [] pred4 = new int [10];

    // put cars on each lane
    car.put_car(1);
    car.put_car(2);
    car.put_car(3);
    car.put_car(4);

    cars1 = car.lane1cars;
    cars2 = car.lane2cars;
    cars3 = car.lane3cars;
    cars4 = car.lane4cars;

    // setting the cars on lanes
    lab1.setText(String.valueOf("CARS: "+car.lane1cars));
    lab2.setText(String.valueOf("CARS: "+car.lane2cars));
     lab3.setText(String.valueOf("CARS: "+car.lane3cars));
      lab4.setText(String.valueOf("CARS: "+car.lane4cars));
      int next_signal;

     while (  counter <10 && !myqueue.isEmpty()){ // the problem area i              have
          //collecting useful loads for prediction
          pred1[counter] = car.lane1cars;
          pred2[counter] = car.lane2cars;
          pred3[counter] = car.lane3cars;
          pred4[counter] = car.lane4cars;

           //collect next signal
          next_signal = ((Integer)myqueue.remove());


          System.out.println(next_signal);//this console prints completely before GUI starts running
           start(next_signal);


myqueue.add(next_signal);
         counter++;            

      }



}
```

the below method is inside the same class with the above :

```
          private void start(final int lane){ 
       ActionListener action = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

            if (red_time >= 0){
                      red1.setText(String.valueOf(red_time));
                      red_time --;
            }
            else if (amb_time >= 0){
                      amb1.setEnabled(true);
                      red1.setEnabled(false);
                      red1.setText(null);
                      amb1.setText(String.valueOf(amb_time));
                      amb_time -- ;
            }
            else if (grn_time >= 0){

                System.out.println();
                      grn1.setEnabled(true);
                      amb1.setEnabled(false);
                      amb1.setText(null);
                      grn1.setText(String.valueOf(grn_time));
                      grn_time -- ;
            }

            else{

                 timer.stop();

                grn1.setText(null);
                grn1.setEnabled(false);
                red1.setEnabled(true);
                reset_time();
                 System.out.println (red_time);


            }




        }
    };
    timer = new Timer(speed,action);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);

        timer.start(); 


}
```

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you have a missing understanding of concurrency (generally), maybe have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), the `while-loop` in your `bulbs ` is a possible source of problems

Comment: can you please help me fix it?